# How do I edit the height of ion-title elements?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am attempting to add a `text-shadow` to an `ion-title` element, but the shadow is getting clipped. How do I avoid this, if possible? Unfortunately, there is no `part` accessible in the shadow DOM, and the `.toolbar-title` element within it is the one I need to resize. Any ideas of how to do this?

https://codepen.io/mattmc318/pen/zYBOVQP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sadly we don't have a `part` to access the title and you can't use `.toolbar-title` either to directly set the height, and many css properties won't work.

I tested in your codepen and seems that you can use `line-height` instead of `height` in your `ion-title` css selector to set the height of your line box:

```
ion-title {
  font-family: 'M PLUS Rounded 1c', var(--ion-default-font);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 32px;
  @include outline(4, rgba(137, 57, 233, 0.5));
}
```